# Vim-like command-line spreadsheet SC - How do you deal with the lack of Undo feature?

Tags: command-line, spreadsheet, undo, sc

I'm looking for a command-line spreadsheet and so far [sc](https://github.com/msharov/sc) is my best find (I explain why at the end of this message).

But [the lack of Undo feature](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55056/how-to-undo-in-spreadsheet-calculator-sc) is killing me. **How do you deal with the lack of this vital missing feature?** 
Right now, when I make a mistake, I either have to correct it manually; or I have to close the file without saving, re-open it, and re-do all the recent changes - which is a pain; in fact, it makes me just want to not use sc at all, which is a shame as it's the only spreadsheet that seems to do everything else I want.

I've come up with a wonky solution (haven't tried it yet): as the F-keys are programmable, I could make one of them commit my spreadsheet in Git, and another one "undo" my recent changes, by reversing to the previous commit. And maybe also one to redo. That's not ideal, really... So I would appreciate any better idea.

Oh, also! Another missing feature of sc is the community. There is not mailing list (nor IRC channel). If there's people around using sc, I might be up for setting up a mailing list so we can exchange questions and ideas. Any takers?

---

Appendix: Why sc is the best command-line spreadsheet for me so far:

- It's still (passively) maintained,
- has Vim key bindings,
- functions can be programmed in any language
- cells can run external commands and return their output in the cell
- can apply colors to cells and text (I use spreadsheets to "tell a story", or to "help me understand something", so I need it to be visually obvious, what values I can manipulate and where the interesting results are)
- can encrypt/decrypt spreadsheets

Here is a bit more info about sc:

- [simple tutorial](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/10699)
- [manual](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/xspread.html) (lists most key bindings)
- [step by step manual](http://www.economics.utoronto.ca/jfloyd/stats/minmansc.pdf)
- [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jaunty/man1/sc.1.html) (That's where you will find most info, really)

And here is the [Github issue for the Undo feature](https://github.com/msharov/sc/issues/5). It is tagged "will take patch", and there is a discussion of different ways the feature could be implemented.

PS: Another command-line spreadsheet you might want to have look at is [teapot](http://www.syntax-k.de/projekte/teapot/), which also seems excellent (and also lacks the Undo feature). In fact it has got excellent features that sc lacks, but personally I would use sc for the Vim key bindings, the colors, and the fact that I can program functions in any language.

PPS: I didn't have enough reputation to post this message with the tag "sc", so I tagged it Vim instead, as Vim users might be interested by this spreadsheet.

Comment: +1 for putting that much effort into a question. I did replace the `vim` tag with `sc` because vim really has nothing to do with it *(besides having vim keybindings)*

Comment: The SCIM project is an update of SC which includes the Undo feature: https://github.com/andmarti1424/scim